# show that in $\mathbb{R^n}$: $\|x\|_2\leqslant\|x\|_1 \leqslant \sqrt n\cdot \|x\|_2$

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, normed-spaces

I need to show that in $\mathbb{R^n}$:  $\|x\|_2\leqslant\|x\|_1 \leqslant \sqrt n\cdot \|x\|_2$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\|x\|_2\leqslant\|x\|_ \infty\leqslant  \|x\|_2$ and that the constants are choosen in an optimal way.

Now I do not understand what exactly is meant by optimal choosing of the constants. The tipp given in the textbook is to take a look at what happens with the unit circles in 2 dimensions. I saw that they intersect at the points that represent the unit vectors and in this case all norms are 1 but not all the inequalities will turn into equalities.

I would be extremely happy for some help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi :) it means, that you cannot improve the constant $\sqrt n$ because there is a vector $x\in \mathbb R^n\setminus\{0\}$ with $\|x\|_1=\sqrt n\|x\|_2$

Answer (score 1):

The relations could be reframed in a more appealing way:

$$\Vert x\Vert_\infty\leq \Vert x\Vert_2\leq \Vert x\Vert_1\tag I\label 1$$

$$\frac{\Vert x\Vert_1}{n}\leq\frac{\Vert x\Vert_2}{\sqrt n}\leq\Vert x\Vert_\infty\tag{II}\label 2$$

for all $x\in\mathbf R^n.$

So, by showing $\eqref 1,\eqref 2,$ the given result could be proved to be true subsequently concluding all these norms are equivalent.

We know $$\Vert x\Vert_2^2=\sum_i \vert x_i\vert^2\leq \left(\sum_i \vert x_i\vert\right)^2=\Vert x\Vert_1^2.$$ Can you show the other part of $\eqref 1$? It only involves using the definition of $\max.$

For $\eqref 2,$ Cauchy-Schwarz comes handy: $$\sum_i \vert x_i\cdot 1\vert \leq \left(\sum_i \vert x_i\vert^2\right)^{1/2}\left( \sum_i 1^2\right)^{1/2}.$$ Divide both sides by $n$ (this is motivated by the result to be proved). The other portion also follows suit using the definition of $\max.$